# In Powershell, How do I get the Values out of an array returned by an object?

Tags: powershell, object

In powershell, if a object returns multiple values for one element, then I can't figure out how to separate those values.

So, for example:

```
'1' | %{@("ValueC_$_.1","ValueC_$_.2","ValueC_$_.3")[0]}
```

Returns ValueC_1.1 as I would expect. But..

```
$Object = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
(1..4) | %{
    $null = $object.Add([pscustomobject] @{
        "PropertyA"="ValueA_$_"
        "PropertyB"="ValueB_$_"
        "PropertyC"=@("ValueC_$_.1","ValueC_$_.2","ValueC_$_.3")
    })
}

$Object | Select-Object PropertyC -First 1 | %{$_[0]}
```

Returns this instead:

> {ValueC_1.1, ValueC_1.2, ValueC_1.3}

So, how do I separate each of those subvalues and specify just the first value of each object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that this is what you're looking for:

```
PS> $Object | % { $_.PropertyC[0] }
ValueC_1.1
ValueC_2.1
ValueC_3.1
ValueC_4.1
```

That is, for each object in `$Object`, you want to return its array-valued `.PropertyC`'s property's 1st element.

Note:

- `%` is a built-in alias of [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), which accepts a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) to execute for each pipeline input object.
- Inside that script block, the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) refers to the pipeline input object at hand.